# Hyperplane Problem

Tags: geometry, discrete-mathematics, computer-science, computational-geometry

Given $M$ points in $\mathbb{R}^{N}$, (where $M$ is larger than $N$) I was wondering if there is an approximation algorithm to find a hyperplane which goes through the origin and also intersects as many points as possible. I believe this problem is NP-Hard, but it would be great if someone can point me to the appropriate paper for this and to the approximations for this problem.

Thank you all beforehand

EDIT: What I meant in the above is that is there a better solution than $O(M^N)$? Is there a better solution than looking at all $M$ choose $N-1$ subspaces defined by the points?

Comment: For a "generic" set of points, no hyperplane exactly contains more than $N - 1$ of the points. (Precisely, among the set of _all_ $M$-tuples, those such that no hyperplane contains $\geq N$ points is an open dense subset.) Do you have a particular way to measure the "total error" for a particular hyperplane so that (say) [principal component analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_component_analysis) can be used?

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Unfortunately, I do not have a particular way to measure this total error. Even if I do, I think this means that for each hyperplane, I would have to look at the remaining points and calculate this total error, which would mean that this step would be rather computationally intensive and the algorithm may not be faster than $O(M^{N})$.

Comment: PCA, which is computationally feasible, minimizes the RMS distances from points to the selected hyperplane. Usually PCA is done to find the _largest_ eigenvalue or few; you want to find the _single smallest_, and project along that axis. Most likely, PCA will give a hyperplane containing _fewer_ than $N - 1$ points, so if containment is essential, PCA isn't your best course of action.